# How to get an angle between a direction faced and a point in 3D space

Tags: c#, trigonometry

The information I have is the vertical angle of the player's vision, the horizontal angle to the point in question, the distance to that point and the point's vertical height.

I've figured out how to get the angle if the player isn't looking up or down (vertical angle) by using the following.

```
float GetVisionAngle(float angleHoriz, float angleVert, float distance, float height)
{
double A = Math.Cos(angleHoriz * (Math.PI / 180)) * distance);
double hypotenuse = Math.Sqrt(distance * distance + height * height);
return (float)(Math.Acos(A / hypotenuse) * (180 / Math.PI));
}
```

[image: Original Method to derive angle between a point in space and player's vision direction]

What I can't figure out is how to get that angle if the player's vision direction is modified by a vertical angle (looking up or down). I've been mulling this over in my head for a few days and I can't figure out a way to do it.

What I'm using this for is to generate a vision cone cutoff. When an object is checked for visibility, the information I have to work with is the angle of the object from the player, the distance to that object, and its height. This initial range check will return an angle from the player's direction of vision and determine whether the object is visible or not.

[image: The walls are set to transparent to show vision range]

Here is a shot of the code in debug using the solution provided by @HABO 
Unfortunately, it always results in a NaN error.

[image: NaN seems to always be returned.]

Converting the angles to radians before using them seems to fix a lot of the numerical errors. I don't understand the formula at the end that converts the previous numbers into the final angle though.
[image: Here is a new set of numbers using some easier to work with figures]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aH = Angle in the horizontal plane between the line of sight (LOS) and the object.  (angleHoriz)

aV = Angle in the vertical plane of the LOS.  (angleVert)

d = Distance to the object in the horizontal plane.  (distance)

h = Height of the object above the horizontal plane.  (height)

dO = Distance from the origin to the object.
   = sqrt( d * d + h * h )

oH = Horizontal offset from the LOS to the object at the base of the wall.
   = sin( aH ) * d

dH = Horizontal distance from the origin to the wall.
   = cos( aH ) * d

hLOS = Height at which the LOS intersects the wall.
     = tan( aV ) * dH

dLOS = Distance from the observer to the LOS at the wall.
     = sqrt( dH * dH + hLOS * hLOS )

dW = Distance along the wall between the line of sight and the object.
   = sqrt( oH * oH + ( h - hLOS ) * ( h - hLOS ) )

answer = acos( ( dLOS * dLOS + dO * dO - dW * dW ) / ( 2 * dLOS * dO ) )
```

Comment: That's very clear and concise but for some strange reason, every single set of variables I plug in is returning Not a Number. I'll write up an example set to show you and hopefully you can see where the error is taking place.

Comment: aH = 45; aV = 10; d = 141.421356; h = 172.8; dO = 223.29317285682123; oH = 120.33593043597216; dH = 74.291748100900179; hLOS = 48.167859272081671; dLOS = 88.540422987145647; dW = 173.2452233598635; answer = NaN;      The problem might be that C# uses radians instead of degrees?

Comment: @Steve - I was trying to work through the geometry step by step to show how to get to the answer.  (Using polar coordinates would also work, though I don't think that .NET has support for 3D polar coordinates.)  It would be wise to use radians for the angles, or convert from degrees or grads as needed.  Mind you, that Pythagoras guy was pretty cutting edge when I learned geometry.  It's likely that I've mucked up somewhere.

Comment: I did some testing and the Math Function does appear to be using Radians instead of Degrees. Converting the angles to radians appears to fix a lot of the strange numbers prior to the final answer. Could you please explain a bit about how the final answer is derived? I follow up until that point but I'm getting a bit lost at the end there. I'll include an updated set of easy numbers for you to look at in the OP.

Comment: @Steve - The final _then a miracle occurs_ step was liberated from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Sine.2C_cosine_and_tangent_rules).  **Mea culpa**: I have edited the last step to include an additional pair of parentheses.  A stupid operator precedence error on my part.  That should give you a result of about 40.5 degrees for your sample values.

Comment: Yup, that did it. From there I just have to change the resulting radian to degrees and the magic happens. Thank you very much for your help. . . Now I get to go about trimming this down as much as possible since it'll be running up to 20,000 times an update =)